# How to reverse a list while preserving the last index?

Tags: python, list, indexing, reverse, except

How I can reverse all the items of a list except the last index?

Example:

```
aList = ['1', '2', 'STAY']
```

And I would want the result to be:

```
aList = ['2', '1', 'STAY']
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `aList = aList[:-1][::-1] + [aList[-1]]`

Answer (score 4):

Very simple with slicing:

```
aList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'STAY']
aList[:-1] = aList[-2::-1]
print(aList)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['4', '3', '2', '1', 'STAY']
> ```

Explanation:

```
aList[:-1] = aList[-2::-1]
       ^            ^   ^
       |            |   |___Travel towards the beginning
       |            |
       |      Start from the second to last element
       |
Assign from first to second to last element
```

Comment: Your explanation *might* be interpreted to mean that `aList[-2::-1] == aList[-2:][::-1]` which is not the case. The sign of the step determines whether the `-2:` part means "start from index 0 up to the second to last element" or "start from the second to last element up to the end of the list".

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Edited it a bit, is it more clear in your opinion now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
alist=['1','2','STAY']  # Your List
fix=alist[-1] # Declaring the last element in alist using negative index
del alist[-1] # Deleting last element
alist.reverse() # Reversing the remaining list
alist.append(fix) # Inserting the last element in alist
```

Print the list to get your required list.